# TP-Link Archer T4u: Unable to go to monitor mode

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, airmon-ng

System: **Kali Linux 2016.1** (hosted on Virtual Box)

Wifi USB Adapter: **TP-Link Archer T4u**

Chipset: **Realtek RTL8812AU**

I have installed these drivers: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux using `make`, then `sudo make install`.

Apparently something went wrong, because when I try:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

I end up with an error about missing files:

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy1    wlan0       ??????       
cat: /sys/class/ieee80211/phy1/device/net/wlan0mon/type: No such file or directory

Newly created monitor mode interface wlan0mon is *NOT* in monitor mode.
Removing non-monitor wlan0mon interface...

WARNING: unable to start monitor mode, please run "airmon-ng check kill"
```

Output from `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Did you make sure they are loaded and used?

Comment: Try to enable monitor mode manually: does it work? `iw dev wlan0 set type monitor`. You will need to install `iw` if it's not installed.

Comment: @phk: yes, they are, @siblynx: it returns `command failed: Operation not supported (-95).`